# Scroll View Is not working in my Android Device

Tags: android, xml

This is XML code of my android app. The problem is my screen is not scrolling down. For testing the scroll view I have given  `android:layout_marginTop="1500dp"` in order to see whether scrollView is working or but it is not working.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#A6A69C"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="1500dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="#95D990" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SELECT DATE" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/in_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="#EAF980">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SELECT TIME" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/in_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The scrollView has to be your **root** element.

Comment: ScrollView s height should be `match_parent`

Comment: @Mueed check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Found your issue remove    `android:layout_marginTop="1500dp"` from your super child .. if you keep a `marginTop` in the child of `ScrollView` that much of a size wont allow you to scroll up. To understand that use like `android:layout_marginTop="50dp"`and see.

If you want to add 1500dp margin ,do it like this and you are good to go!

if you keep a `layout_marginTop`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A6A69C"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            // you have added 1500 margin-top here - remove it
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="1500dp"   // <---------added 1500 margin-top here
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="#95D990" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SELECT DATE" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/in_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="#EAF980">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SELECT TIME" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/in_time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

p.s : remove the comments that i added when you run :P

[image]